# display directories and files by size order c#

Tags: c#

Trying to list all the directories and files on a machine and sort them into size.
I get a list of the file names and their sizes but it won't stick them in order... Any suggestions greatly appreciated! Cheers

```
     //create instance of drive which contains files
        DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(@"C:\");
        //find the root directory path
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

        try
        {

            //EnumerateFiles increases the performance and sort them
            foreach (var fi in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(f =>f.Length).ToList())
            {
                try
                {

                    //Display each file
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}", fi.FullName, fi.Length);

                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UnAuthTop)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", UnAuthTop.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Other than the `ToList` being unnecessary (as well as hurting performance by forcing a pass of the entire collection before it can be enumerated) and a nested `try-catch` that seems arbitrary given the provided code, I don't see a problem that would prevent the collection from being sorted. What is the output that it is producing, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Yeh I originally had it without the ToList method but it gave the same outcome... It gives me the full list of files but not in size order... but with all the other files within the same folder, so as they are processed I think

Comment: The code assumes that the FileInfo.Length property value does not change.  Files do change their length, happens when a process is writing to the file.  How detrimental that could be is not entirely obvious to me, there is some caching going on inside FileInfo, it is also pretty dangerous when sorting.

Comment: I've used a similar code as the one in my answer for many years, to display files from folders that many designers contribute to dynamically. So far no problems. When a file is being uploaded and the list is called, it shows the file with length 0, and continues to the next item. When the file has completed uploading and the screen is refreshed, it show the file with the proper length.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
// get your folder
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(you path here);

    // create a list of files from that folder
    List<FileInfo> fi = di.GetFiles().ToList();

    // pass the files in a sorted order
    var files =  fi.Where(f => f.FullName != null).OrderByDescending(f => f.Length);
```

In this example: files will contain a list if files from the current folder level, sorted by file.length .

You might want to check if fi is not null before trying to pass it to the variable files. Then, you can iterate over files with the foreach.

[ UPDATE ]

As @Abion47 points out, there doesn't seem to be much difference between the Op's code and my solution. From what I read in the OP, the OP is not getting a sorted list, which is the desired result.

What I see that might make a difference is that, by using the EnumerateFiles, you start enumerating and can act on file info before the entire collection of files is returned. It's great for handling enormous amounts of files. And, more efficient than GetFiles, for performing operations on individual files as they become available.

Since that is the case, you might not be able to sort the returned files properly, until the complete collection has been enumerated.

By using GetFiles, you have to wait for it to return the whole collection. Making it easier to sort.

I don't think that GetFiles is ideal for handling huge collections. In that case, I would divide the work into steps or use some other approach.

Comment: That ToList is redundant.

Comment: @CSharpie perhaps your right about ToList being redundant here, but it satisfies both sides of the equal sign and has shown no significant impact on working with thousands of files that get displayed almost at a blink of an eye.

Comment: Why the check agains a FullName being null?

Comment: Why not! You never know what people try to upload. Some names have shown up to be invisible or inaccessible, to name a few instances.

Comment: This code looks functionally identical to the one OP presented. The only notable differences are in using `GetFiles` instead of `EnumerateFiles` and `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`. All other things being equal, I can't see this code producing different results than what OP already has.